# how to create reports in Cost Management for Azure and send them in email

Tags: azure, azure-billing

so we were using Cloudyn in Azure Cost Management which produces the monthly cost reports. but now we have the AWS connector setup in Azure Cost Management and I need to reproduce the monthly cost reports that break down the total cost for all Azure and AWS environments by the environment.

is there any way to create these reports in Cost Management for Azure and if/how to save them and auto-send them in emails at the end of every month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure does not have a way to provide Cost Management reports on a schedule. The Cost Management API allows you to query data which could be use to generate a monthly report, for example with a Logic App.

If your reporting requirements are complex, depending on your agreement type, you could pull the data from the API into a SQL database and run Power BI reports on the database. An example project which demonstrates downloading cost data to a SQL DB for enterprise agreement customers is available here: https://github.com/venushaa/AzureUsageDetailsDownload

Comment: Thanks, Matthew for responding quickly. my reporting requirement is not complex, I just need to have a chart that breaks down the cost per platform (Azure, AWS) and per subscription/account for month just completed.  Minimally I want to save these reports, so I can just run them, so I don't have to keep changing the group by or date range filters every time at the end of the month to get monthly reports. how do you think I should go about this?  Thank you. @Matthew